# How to show Validation errors when implemented in the model in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

So I've done a lot searching but I can't find an answer for the following problem. I'm implementing my Validation trough DataAnnotations at Model level but I cannot find a way to show the error message if the field is invalid. I can get the control on the View to change the border color as the field turns itself Invalid but as I said I cannot find a way to bind the error Message coming from the model, I can get it to work if do the properties and validation at ViewModel level but I'm trying to implement it at Model level as it seems the most logical thing to do.

My Model ObservableObject is my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class Customer : ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [Required]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Error // Part of the IDataErrorInfo Interface
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName] // Part of the IDataErrorInfo Interface
    {
        get { return OnValidate(propertyName); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates current instance properties using Data Annotations.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual string OnValidate(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);

        string error = string.Empty;
        var value = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>(1);

        var context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName };

        var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, results);

        if (!result)
        {
            var validationResult = results.First();
            error = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

my ViewModel has:

```
public Customer SelectedCustomer
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedCustomer;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedCustomer = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanModify");
            }
        }
```

and on my view to edit each field i got:

```
            <Label>First Name</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.FirstName, 
                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Label>Last Name</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.LastName, 
                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

this changes color when a field turns invalid but as I said so far I haven't found a way to display the error message that comes along.

Comment: The process is pretty much the same as binding a textbox to `SelectedCustomer.FirstName`. Have a string property in your view model that includes the error message and bind it to a label on the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` of your `UIElement`.

Gist:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
  <DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <Grid Width="12" Height="12">
        <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" 
        Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"

                 ></Ellipse>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Heavy" 
        FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
                   ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, 
                   Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                   >X</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontWeight="12" Margin="2,0,0,0" 
               Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, 
               Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
               ></TextBlock>                    
    </StackPanel>
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder 
    x:Name="ErrorAdorner" ></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
  </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690130/Simple-Validation-in-WPF) and [here](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/binding-to-validationerrors0-without-creating-debug-spew/)